# Error handling in JAVA - Check correct input type

Tags: java, error-handling

Not sure where i'm going wrong, please help. Trying to check if the user has only entered an integer. Error showing strInpit cannot be resolved to a variable.

```html
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Salary{ 
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int num = 0;
    String strIntput;
    boolean valid = false;
    

    // setup scanner
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    // loop to check for valid input
    while(valid == false){
      //prompt user to enter
      System.out.println("Enter your salary per year");
      // grab input from keyboard
      strInput = in.nextLine();
      // try to convert String to int
      try{
        num = Integer.parseInt(strInput);
        valid = true;
      }
      catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Error - enter an integer value.");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("your salary is " + num);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo `strIntput` vs. `strInput`

Comment: I am voting to close this question because it was caused by a typo, and as such it is unlikely to be of help to future visitors to this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have named the variable as `String strIntput;`

while declaring it..but you are using strInput everywhere else

so change `String strIntput;` **TO** `String strInput;`

Comment: For reference: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366135/12567365)

Answer (score 0):

There is another method which you can use:
#Scaner.nextInt(); It will get Integer value from console or, in another case, will throw an exception